# Entity Framework Find By Example?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

Coming from a Java background with ORM's it seems that all of them always had a FindByExample (KODO, Hibernate, etc).  I have been surprised that I haven't been able to find the same in EF.  I am using the code first method.  Am I just missing something?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this natively with EF. At best you would have to inspect an existing object and construct a query based on each property.

NHibernate on the other hand does have this capability (just like it's Java cousin).

Comment: Thanks I was affraid of that. :(